# Reconstruct odt file with missing content.xml file

Tags: file, openoffice.org, corruption

I have an .odt file that's corrupt. I looked online and apparently if you can get to the content.xml file, there's a chance the file can be repaired. However, in my case, when I convert the file to a .zip and extract it, I don't have that file. However, the .odt file is 2.9MB and has content in it when you convert it to a .txt file.

How can I recreate the content.xml file from the .txt file?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did not downvote you, but the reason someone else downvoted you is probably because this question is not really complete... for example, you do not show what the Configurations2 folder contains, and since you do not provide the corrupted file, nobody can really know where exactly it is corrupted... Do any errors occur when unzipping?

Comment: *"Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)."*

Comment: Try a disk recovery program to recover the odt file before corruption. Hope it works

Answer (score 3):

You might not want to hear this, but depending on where the corruption happened, there is nothing you can do.

The idea behind the method you are describing is that if the corruption only concerns, for example, the styles.xml, you can still recover the contents by looking at content.xml. For more details on this, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification#Format_internals

However, from your zip extract, it looks like the only uncorrupted file is styles.xml, which doesn't help you much.

What you can try to do is the following: Rename your .odt-File so that it ends in .zip, and then try to recover that file using one of the multitude of tools available on the internet, for example [here](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-damaged-or-corrupted-zip-archive/), until you get a valid content.xml file.